# Error with matplotlib - "could not find Qt platform plugin windows ..."

Tags: python-3.x, qt, matplotlib

Please, before telling me I am re-posting, I have not been able to find a working solution/ work around for this issue (below) - Also may be because I don't know what I'm doing while trying to fix it.

I am trying to run the following code for a school project where I want to display a graph using python 3:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

Originally I was getting an error with the NumPy module not importing "Multiarray". I fixed this by installing the module via "Anaconda" with Windows 10.

Now when I try to run the code I get the following popup, Thanks for any solutions or work-rounds.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this was due to my own stupidity, I had only copied across the site packages from anaconda3, but I needed to copy across everything else. It works now